# How to execute a smart contract and get Events without broadcasting transaction to MainNet?

Tags: transactions

Is it possible to emulate execution of a transaction without sending it to MainNet?

I can't use testrpc or private network for it because my contracts use data from other contracts in MainNet.

How miners execute pending transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) (former testrpc) to create a fork of another running blockchain.

> `-f` or `--fork`: Fork from another currently running Ethereum client at a given block. Input should be the HTTP location and port of the other client, e.g. `http://localhost:8545`. You can optionally specify the block to fork from using an `@` sign: `http://localhost:8545@1599200`.